# how to implement xml like this example

Tags: android, xml

[image: Here is my example]

how to implement xml like this example
without write java code !
and Proportionality with all screens

Comment: Use something like ConstraintLayout

Comment: XML  is not a code

Comment: you can use `relative layout` or `constrain layout`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Edited !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `relative layout` (or `constraint layout`) but I prefer `relative`... Good Luck!